# How do unhealthy instances get onto my AWS load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

We are using CodeDeploy to load code onto our instances as they boot up. Our intention was that they would not be added to the LB prior to the code being loaded. To do this, we set a health check which looked for one of the files being deployed. What we have found is that some times instances without code are created (I assume code deploy failed) and these instances are staying in the LB even when marked unhealthy? How is this possible? Is this related to the grace period? Shouldn't instances that are unhealthy be removed automatically?

Comment: Being registered with the load balancer and being actually sent traffic by the load balancer are two different things.  When an instance isn't healthy, the ELB doesn't send it any traffic... but the load balancer can't actually do the health checks without the instance first being registered to the load balancer... so it isn't clear to me what part of the behavior you consider to be incorrect.

Comment: We had an unhealthy instance which was still on the load balancer. It war marked as unhealthy, and we were having a large number of 5xx errors until we manually removed it. Additionally, I was looking for some clarification on how to ensure an instance is never sent traffic until it passes a health check, and if "grace period" allows unhealthy instances to receive traffic during this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found a large part of my problem: My Auto-scale group was set to use EC2 health checks and not my ELB health check. This resulted in the instance not being terminated. The traffic may have continued to flow longer to this crippled instance due to the need the need for a very long unhealthy state before having traffic completely stopped.